# How to fix error "could not find store in context connect(App)" when unit testing connected components?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

**EDIT: Instead of deleting, I revised my question. Sorry about that**

I am trying to get rid of an error which I originally thought was me not "properly" connecting my component to the store. I would appreciate it if someone can provide a fix for this as I am now beginning to suspect that it is a bug.

So as it turns out, testing components that are 'connected' to Redux store takes a little more effort to set up.

Following the official docs from https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components, I now have this:

**In my App.js**

```
export class App extends Component{
           ....
}

......

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

**and inside the default App.test.js provided by create-react-app :**

I import the "unconnected" component, by importing the named import like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
//import unconnected component
import { App } from './App';


 it('renders without crashing', () => {
   const div = document.createElement('div');
   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div); // where i get the persistent error
   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
 });
```

However, the problem "could not find store in the connect(app)" still persists. What am I doing wrong?

I am using VSCode with Jest extension installed, anyone replicate the same behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone viewing this, you need to export the class itself, not the default export which is connected to Redux, like so:

```
export class App extends Component{
       ....
}

......

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

In your test, import the class:

```
//correct
import {App} from '../path';
//wrong, importing the default
import App from '../path';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `app` in the index.js is not a React component. You need to do this instead:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: not the problem, thanks anyway. i was asking the wrong question apparently.  the problem had nothing to do with how i used connect but a flaw on how I wrote my tests in app.test.js

Answer (score 0):

`import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from 'path to your store'`

....

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
 <Provider>,
document.getElementById('root');
)
```

You should get your HTML file...

[Here is documentation react redux](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider)